# How to make an Image as large as possible while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an image which is smaller than the container I would like it to fit inside of. I would like the image to stretch, keeping it's aspect ratio, to it's largest possible size.

To illustrate this problem:

```
<ImageView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/thumbnail"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

The `ImageView` above would be stretched to fill the width of the container. The `@drawable` it contained would also stretch along the x axis to fit the width of `ImageView` which is perfect. The problem however is that the dimension labelled `wrap_content`, in this case height, remains the same size as the `@drawable`s initial height.

I have read the documentation regarding ScaleType [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) and can't find the answer there.

The following image describes the above code:

[image] [image]

```
  Current behaviour               Desired Behaviour
```

***Edit***

An `ImageView` given `scaleType="fitCenter"` will accurately expand/shrink the `@drawable` inside of it to grow as large as possible while retaining it's aspect ratio.

The `ImageView`s dimensions are defined before the `@drawable` is scaled in any way. The `ImageView` dimensions are not effected by scaling of it's contained `@drawable`.

Comment: To me, this is a common problem, one that I've never found a clean solution for. Add in a background 9-patch for a frame, and it's even worse to try and fix. I'm pretty sure this is something you'll have to do programmatically, but it'll be nice if someone does have a solution for this.

Comment: +1 for a fully described question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**XML**

The only solution to this in XML is to use `"match_parent"` or a discrete maximum value instead of `"wrap_content"` where possible. This will ensure the `ImageView` is the correct size, which will then meaning adding `scaleType="fitCenter"` will ensure the `@drawable` will then scale correctly.

**Programatically**

It's ugly, but you can resize the ImageView after it's dimensions have been given discrete values:

```
    final ImageView thumbnailView = (ImageView) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);  

    ViewTreeObserver thumbnailViewVto = thumbnailView.getViewTreeObserver();
    thumbnailViewVto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        private boolean changed = false;
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if(!changed) {
                Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumbnail);
                float heighToWidthRatio = image.getIntrinsicWidth()/image.getIntrinsicHeight();
                int height = thumbnailView.getHeight();

                thumbnailView.setLayoutParams(
                        new LayoutParams(
                                (int) (height * heighToWidthRatio), height));
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

```
    final ImageView thumbnailView = (ImageView) toReturn.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);  

    thumbnailView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Remove the GlobalOnLayout Listener so it only fires once.
            thumbnailView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)

            // Find the images Height to Width ratio
            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thumbnail);
            float heighToWidthRatio = image.getIntrinsicWidth()/image.getIntrinsicHeight();

            // Use this ratio to discover the ratio of the ImageView to allow it to perfectly contain the image.
            int height = thumbnailView.getHeight();
            thumbnailView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                (int) (height * heighToWidthRatio), height));
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is boolean `changed` for?

Comment: It's so the onGlobalLayout listener doesn't fire repeatedly. Older and wiser, I would now just remove the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` from the `ViewTreeObserver` as the first action in the `onGlobalLayout()` method. (See my edit for details)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want fitCenter, which uses  [Matrix.ScaleToFit CENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER).

Comment: This keep's the aspect ratio but the image doesn't fill anymore. This would work if the height of the ImageView was correct which can be done programatically but I would like it to happen through XML.

Comment: @Graeme - From the link: "Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. *At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly.* The result is centered inside dst." - Their description seems to imply that the image will be stretched to fill either the width or height.  Maybe it only shrinks to fit, but doesn't stretch to fit?

Comment: That description is exactly correct - since one of the dimensions is set to "wrap_content" however the size initialisation of the ImageView seems to happen before the scaling, therefore the height of View is already set and it is using the smallest axis to fit to, without enlarging it.